# Overshooting when traversing between two points with a set velocity

Tags: c#, 2d, movement

I'm creating a prototype for something I may make into a game and I've run into difficulty in creating a method to move a ship along a line between two points. While it reaches the end point, it either over/undershoots the end point on either the x or y. Applying a floor or ceiling arbitrarily won't work for all circumstances depending on what direction I'm travelling either.

I'm certain there must be a better way.

I've got the logic of creating a line between them using ArcTan2 but I'm finding that I will always get an over shot of the destination. I think I've been toying with it too long to arrive at a sensible solution that's not a kludge fixed with several conditional statements. I'm using C# but only while I'm at this stage.

A few definitions:

| Name | Type | Initial Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **xpos** | float | 4 | The current horizontal position of the ship |
| **ypos** | float | 12 | The current vertical position of the ship |
| **xhead** | float | 14 | The horizontal position of the destination |
| **yhead** | float | 7 | The vertical position of the destination |
| **speed** | float | 2 | The ship's speed, measured in position units per step |
| **dist** | float | 11.18034 | The current distance between the ship and its destination |
| **deltaX** | float | 10 | The signed offset from the ship to the destination, horizontally |
| **deltaY** | float | -5 | The signed offset from the ship to the destination, vertically |
| **angle** | float) | -0.4636476 | The angle the ship needs to travel, measured in radians counter-clockwise from the positive x axis |

Using the standard Euclidian distance between **xpos**,**ypos** and **xhead**,**yhead** I obtain the distance and then by using *Atan2* and the deltas I get the **angle** above.

here is my current code (ToPoint is an ext method turning xpos and ypos into a PointF as is Distance. headToPoint is **xhead**,**yhead** to a PointF):

```
        trail = new List<PointF>();
        steps = new List<PointF>();
        stepsIX = 0;
        float origDistance = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xhead - xpos, 2) + Math.Pow(yhead - ypos, 2));
        float segSize = origDistance / speed;
        float distance = origDistance;
        float lastdistance = distance;

        float deltaX = xhead - xpos;
        float deltaY = yhead - ypos;
        float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

        steps.Add(this.ToPoint());

        while (distance >= 0)
        {
          PointF last = steps[steps.Count() - 1];
          lastdistance = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xhead - last.X, 2) + Math.Pow(yhead - last.Y, 2));
          float nx = last.X + (float)(speed * Math.Cos(angle));
          float ny = last.Y + (float)(speed * Math.Sin(angle));
          PointF np = new PointF(nx, ny);
          distance = np.Distance(headToPoint());


          if (distance > lastdistance)
          {
            break;
          }


          steps.Add(np);
        }
```

Output of **steps**:

```
START: {X=4, Y=12}
TARGET: {X=14, Y=7} 
--Steps--
{X=4, Y=12}
{X=5.788855, Y=11.10557}
{X=7.577709, Y=10.21115}
{X=9.366564, Y=9.316718}
{X=11.15542, Y=8.422291}
{X=12.94427, Y=7.527864}
{X=14.73313, Y=6.633436}
```

Many thanks to anyone who reads this or has any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done much more simply. We don't need trigonometry and angles where simple vector normalization and arithmetic suffices.

```
bool StepToward(
        ref float currentX, ref float currentY,
        float destinationX, float destinationY,
        float maxStepDistance
) {
    // Compute the offset from our current position to the destination.
    float dX = destinationX - currentX;
    float dY = destinationY - currentY;

    // Get our distance away (we could defer this square root, but the
    // majority of the time we have to do it anyway, so let's bite the bullet.
    float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);

    // If we're within one step of our destination, reach it exactly,
    // and report back that we have arrived (true).
    if (distance <= maxStepDistance) {
        currentX = destinationX;
        currentY = destinationY;
        return true;
    }

    // Otherwise, get an offset vector in the direction of our destination,
    // clamped to the length of our maximum allowable step.
    // Use it to advance one step distance toward the destination.
    float scale = maxStepDistance / distance;
    currentX += dX * scale;
    currentY += dY * scale;

    // Report back that we still have farther to go.
    return false;
}
```

Your loop can then be something like:

```
// Log starting point.
steps.Add(ToPoint());

// Step until we reach the destination.
while (!StepToward(ref xpos, ref ypos, headX, headY, speed)) {
   // Recording each intermediate step we take.
   steps.Add(steps.Add(ToPoint());
}

// Log our arrival at the destination.
steps.Add(ToPoint());
```

---

You could also do this in one big batch:

```
// Compute the offset and distance from our start position to the destination.
float deltaX = headX - posx;
float deltaY = headY - posy;
float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

// Compute how many steps it will take to reach it at this speed.
float stepCount = distance / speed;
int wholeStepCount = (int)stepCount;

// Compute an incremental movement to apply with each step.
float scale = speed / distance;
float stepX = deltaX * scale;
float stepY = deltaY * scale;

// Add whole steps 0...n to our list.
for (int i = 0; i <= stepCount; i++) {
    steps.Add(new PointF(posx + i * stepX, posy + i * stepY));
}

// If there's any remainder, add our fractional step to arrive exactly.
if (wholeStepCount < stepCount) {
    steps.Add(new PointF(headX, headY));
}
```